# Javascript not triggering with href jquery mobile - data transition with window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm finding trouble with jquery mobile, when I change page with

```
 <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'page.html'"
value="New Page">
```

everything works fine, but I want to add a transition, so i tried to chage my code to

```
<a data-transition="slide" href="page.html>New Page</a>
```

but in the new page all javascript works bad, layout of page doesn't load in a proper way and javascript code in the main files doesn't trigger (all var that I declared in js results undefined and if I go back to home page with a href slide menu remain blocked at half width)

So i think to avoid this problem leaving window.location.href but I would need page transition, how can I manage to have both transition and js working properly?

Main:

```
<div id="home" class="upage-content">
<a href="join.html" data-transition="slide">Join</a>
                        </div>
```

Join:

```
<body>

        <div class="uwrap">

            <div class="upage" id="mainpage" style="min-height:100% !important;" data-role="page">

    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js" data-ver="0"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsDjPNTwvkFNGFQp-AN6A6xF5N7_3Pxx0&amp;sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main3.js"></script>
<div class="upage-outer">

                <div data-role="header" class="headclass" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0">
                    <h1>JOIN</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using page transitions, jQuery mobile pre fetches the page to animate it in, if the javascript isn't working it is most likely because the javascript on the page you are animating to is not loading. jQuery mobile will only fetch the contents from the page within the

```
 data-role="page"
```

div. So in order to get the page working properly, you must include all javascript resources within the   section of your main page. and use

```
 <a data-transition="slide" href="page.html>New Page</a>
```

Comment: I included in main-page so inside body, but now jquery doesn't stop loading, looks like is in loop and console log nothing

Comment: is not online at the moment, I added the interested part

Comment: This might not solve all your problems, but I have experienced issues in the past when referencing javascript with the `type="application/javascript"` type. You can remove type completely from all scripts or set it to `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Thanks removed that type from all script, but the problem still remain